# Manipulating collada texture data while loading it (the .jpg itself)

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I want to manipulate the texture image data (e.g. modifying the .jpg header text) while loading the .jpg texture using three.js.

How could I do this? Is the texture data reacheable somewhere in the code for example as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2D `<canvas>`as the texture source and thus use HTML5 canvas API for the image data manipulation before uploading the `<canvas>` as texture data to GPU.

Examples exist here (for resizing overly big JPEGs)

Just create canvas

https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/showobjects/framedimage.js#L134

Do drawImage() on it from the orignal texture data

https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/showobjects/framedimage.js#L165

And then you can use it as the texture source like with `<img>`

https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/renderers/three.js#L396

Comment: Hmm, sorry! Maybe I wasn't detailed enough. I'm using collada models and textures on them. So I want to manipulate my collada textures. Do you familiar to this too?

Comment: I am not famliar with Collada loader. Please update your question with more details.